/dev/sda2 4TB hardware isn't writeable
My work environment is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
My path to /media/yueli/Data directory is a 4TB hardware mounted at /dev/sda2. It isn't writable.
Data:

4TB:


That is shows fuse, is this NTFS or worse FAT32? If used with Windows did Windows use fast startup which sets a hibernation flag preventing the Linux NTFS driver from writing? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

@oldfred Thanks. Windows is ntfs, Ubuntu is ext4.   Then format 4T hardware to exfat.

For larger partitions and use with Windows NTFS is still better. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT
The standard exFAT implementation is not journaled and only uses a single file allocation table and free space map.
But exFAT will store larger files than FAT32. But still should not be used for larger partitions as chkdsk may take forever.
And it does not have Linux ownership & permissions.

@oldfred Thank you so much for your great help!

I think you don't have permissions to write on that partition.
Try mounting that disk and write on it with upser user privileges.
sudo mkdir /media/yueli/data_v2
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/yueli/data_v2
cd /media/yueli/data_v2
sudo touch test1

If you don't have any data on that disk I suggest try using Disks which a GUI application for recreating partition but this time allow others to write on that disk.

If Windows format, ownership & permissions cannot be set. The are set only by default mount parameters.

You are right Mr. @oldfred , just wanted to help that poor guy, he needs to learn more about linux/unix.
